# How to print MSM R package results in Rmarkdown MS Word output?

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown, markov

I am using Rmarkdown and Kniter in Rstudio to make MS Word document. However, my results are from MSM package. This is my code in the .rmd sript:

```
knitr::kable(pmatrix.msm(xdata.msm),caption = "Transition probability matrix.")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ""msm.est"" to a data.frame
Calls: <Anonymous> ... format_args -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.default
```

How do I nicely print the MSM model results in Word. Please help me to solve. this.

**Update:**

Conversion to dataframe gives: `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ""msm.est"" to a data.frame.` 
I need to add caption to `pmatrix.msm(xdata.msm)`.

This is my msm object:

```
dput(xdata.msm)
structure(c(0.867104394602623, 0.0297597288741373, 0.0111688422294673, 
0.0436200880979502, 0.937379027520689, 0.0642139547902726, 0.0892755172994266, 
0.0328612436051735, 0.92461720298026), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("State 1", "State 2", "State 3"), c("State 1", "State 2", 
    "State 3")), class = "msm.est")
```

**Update:** `as.data.frame.matrix()` works for some but not for all. please see this object:

```
dput(pnext.msm(xdata.msm))
structure(list(estimates = structure(c(0, 0.493157008697057, 
0.141450173196988, 0.312417736561033, 0, 0.858549826803012, 0.687582263438967, 
0.506842991302943, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("State 1", 
"State 2", "State 3"), c("State 1", "State 2", "State 3"))), 
    L = structure(c(0, 0.404769718769504, 0.0851255671695353, 
    0.229501053449466, 0, 0.775032294188692, 0.599692174664181, 
    0.416275351504334, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), U = structure(c(0, 
    0.583724648495666, 0.224967705811308, 0.400307825335819, 
    0, 0.914874432830465, 0.770498946550534, 0.595230281230496, 
    0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))), .Names = c("estimates", "L", "U"), class = "msm.est")

Warning in seq_len(ncols) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
Error in seq_len(ncols) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.data.frame.matrix(xdata.msm)` instead of `as.data.frame(xdata.msm)`. That is, call the `matrix` method for `as.data.frame` explicitly. This is because R can't tell that an object of this class is also a matrix, and the package author neglected to provide a data frame coercion method.

Comment: Thanks. +1 It worked for some but not for all. please help with other msm model object

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error message is pretty clear. `kable` deals well with matrices or data frames. Your object is something else and converting it to a data frame doesn't work. You'd have to convert the msm results to a data frame and then you could use `kable`. Otherwise, simply print out the result of `pmatrix.msm(xdata.msm)`.

Comment: conversion to dataframe gives: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""msm.est"" to a data.frame.    I need to add caption to pmatrix.msm(xdata.msm)

Comment: Please share your `msm.est` object (i.e. `pmatrix.msm(xdata.msm)`) using `dput()`

Comment: Please see my msm.est object.